# Upper bounds for $\zeta(s)$ on the critical line

Tags: riemann-zeta-function

In Graham and Kolesnik's "Van der Corput's Method of Exponential Sums" they mention the results of Watt (1989) who obtained $\zeta(1/2 + it) = O(t^{89/560 + \epsilon})$.

Is anyone aware of more recent improvements to this bound (and perhaps the methods involved)?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the current record is $O(t^{32/205})$ (where $ 32/205 \approx .156 $) [due to Huxley](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/90/1/1) in 2005.